# C++ __builtin_* functions source codes

Tags: c++, built-in

I want to learn how can I find source codes of __builtin functions like `__builtin_cbrt()` in C++. If you know, Can you help me?

Comment: Functions that start with `__` are special implementation-specific functions. They aren't necessarily implemented by C++ source code. They can be implemented as assembly or just treated uniquely by the compiler.

Comment: You would need to check the source code for the compiler you are using.

Comment: By definition, platform-specific functions `__builtin_*` are _builtin_ in the compiler. They are not implemented in C++ in a library. Of course, you can look in the source code of _Clang_ or _GCC_ themselves, but it will be hard to spot precisely where those functions are handled.

Comment: what research did you do on your own? Have you at least found out your compiler sources?

Comment: @KamilCuk I was trying to find source code of ```std::cbrt()```, i find it in STL library on local, it calss ```__builtin_cbrt()``` but I couldn't find it's source code...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I want to learn how can I find

First become acquainted with the language you are working with - learn C and C++ programming languages. Learn about the tools like `git` and `autotools` and the environment around these programming languages. Become familiar with the tool set needed browsing files - at least `grep`, but I recommend it's (way) faster alternatives - "the silver searcher" `ag` or `ack`, but be aware of tools like ctags or GNU Global.

Then research. GNU projects are available open source - it's very easy to find source code of GNU projects, nowadays they are even mirrored on github.

Then it's just a "feeling" or "experience". Surely a project will have builtins functions in a file named "builtins.c" or something similar. Be curious, reasonable and inventive. If you would want to add a builtin function to a codebase, where would you put it? Become familiar with the project structure you are working with. And expect big and old projects to have stuff scattered all over the place.

First I find [gcc sources with builtins.def `(BUILT_IN_CBRT, "cbrt"`](https://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc/blob/master/gcc/builtins.def#L317), and some references of [BUILT_IN_CBRT in builtins.c](https://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc/blob/master/gcc/builtins.c#L14251).

After cloning the `gcc` repository I scan for `BUILT_IN_CBRT` macro name. Browsing the code leads me to `CASE_CFN_CBRT` macro name, which leads me to [fold-const-call.c](https://code.woboq.org/gcc/gcc/fold-const-call.c.html#622):

```
CASE_CFN_CBRT:
  return do_mpfr_arg1 (result, mpfr_cbrt, arg, format);
```

By the name of the file `fold-const-call.c` I suspect this part of code is taken only when folding a constant call.

From there I can browse google about `mpfr_cbrt` symbol, which leads me to GNU MPFR library. I find clone of MPRF library on github and search for a file named `cbrt`, I find [cbrt.c with mpfr_cbrt() sources](https://github.com/qsnake/mpfr/blob/master/src/cbrt.c#L45) with the source of cbrt within MPRF library. This is the code that will be called and will compute `cbrt` of a number when `__builtin_cbrt` is folded inside a constant expression, I suspect.

When not in constnat expression, I suspect that [fold_const_call_ss]https://code.woboq.org/gcc/gcc/fold-const-call.c.html#_ZL18fold_const_call_ssP10real_value11combined_fnPKS_PK11real_format) is not called at all, instead some [`fold_const_*` function](https://code.woboq.org/gcc/gcc/fold-const-call.c.html#_Z15fold_const_call11combined_fnP9tree_nodeS1_) returns to gcc that the expression cannot be constantly folded so a call to the actual `cbrt()` standard function is generated.